# ASP.Net Core API bind model int Ids to custom Id objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, design-patterns

I have structs which represents Id's for different types. That structs have int property "Id", public constructor with (int id) parameter and implements IEquatable interface. I want my ASP.Net Core WebAPI application to somehow bind those structs to incoming integer Ids in query. I know that there are custom model binders, but to use it I need to implement custom model binders for all query models, because marking each key-struct property with custom model binder not enough - I need to register custom model binder provider, where I switch ModelType and return single model binder, like so:

```
    public class CustomModelBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
    {
        public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
        {
            if (context == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
            }

            if (context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(DogQueryModel))
            {
                return new BinderTypeModelBinder(typeof(DogQueryModelBinder));
            }
```

So I can't create just one model binder for each Id struct - need to create it for each query model.

To make it clear I will provide some example code of that struct, query model and action:

```
    public struct DogKey : IEquatable<DogKey>
    {
        public DogKey(int id)
        {
            Id = id;
        }

        public int Id { get; }

        #region IEquatable implementation
        #endregion IEquatable implementation
    }

    public class DogQueryModel
    {
        public DogKey Id { get; set; }
        public SomeOtherKey OtherId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    [HttpGet("dog")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IList<DogResultModel>>> GetDogs([FromQuery]DogQueryModel dogQueryModel)
    {
        //use dogQueryModel.Id as DogKey struct
    }
```

I want to query it like this: `https://localhost/api/v1/dogs/dog?id=1&otherId=2&Name=dogname`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so by implementing a [type converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typeconverter?view=netframework-4.8), it's mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.0#recommendations-and-best-practices) but sadly without a sample. I've implemented the necessary bits to get your sample working.

I've added some generic constraints in the KeyConverter class that seem to fit your needs, they are not necessary though.

```
public class KeyConverter<T> : TypeConverter
    where T : struct, IEquatable<T>
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        if (sourceType == typeof(string))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        var stringValue = value as string;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringValue))
        {
            if(int.TryParse(stringValue, out int parsed))
            {
                return Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), new object[] { parsed });
            }
        }
        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }
}
```

Then decorate your key classes with the `TypeConverter` attribute.

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(KeyConverter<DogKey>))]
public struct DogKey : IEquatable<DogKey>
{
    public DogKey(int id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }

    public int Id { get; }

    #region IEquatable implementation
    #endregion IEquatable implementation

}

[TypeConverter(typeof(KeyConverter<CatKey>))]
public struct CatKey : IEquatable<CatKey>
{
    public CatKey(int id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }

    public int Id { get; }

    #region IEquatable implementation
    #endregion IEquatable implementation

}
```

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm! The only downside is swagger shows that parameter key as string and I didn't find any solution how to mark that key for swagger to show it as integer.

Comment: Depending on what you use you can customize the swagger info: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle#modifying-generated-schemas