# ASP.NET Core 6.0 MVC - ModelState is always invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

My `ModelState` is always invalid, and have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I show only part of my model because it's failing also on first part so I don't need show deeper models.

```cs
public class PriceOffer
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime ValidUntilDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("Customer")]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    public Customer Customer { get; set; }

    // Relationship
    public ICollection<Window> Windows { get; set; }
}
```

In this model I have a foreign key `CustomerID` which should be link to a `Customer`.

This is my controller for getting data from the form:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> SaveOffer(PriceOffer offer)
{
    var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
         return;
    }
}
```

At this point I have a breakpoint. I have checked what is in `Offer` object. In the object is

```
Customer = null
CustomerId = 1
```

So the `Id` of the customer was sent from HTML, but it's not linked to the object. In the var errors says

> ErrorMessage = "The Customer field is required."

What am I missing here? Why controller does not bind the `ID` of customer to the `Customer` object? I checked many videos and tutorials and its work but in my case does not.

Comment: Are you only passing `CustomerId = 1` from the view and expecting that, upon receiving the `1`, the `Customer` object with that `Id` will be automatically retrieved from the database?

Comment: Yes Im just passing ID from hidden <input> once you are in detail page of the customer. But same problem I have for dropdown object which are loaded from DB and shown in HTML. Once form is submitted IDs are sent to controller but ModelState is not valid because its not linked to the objects. But I have checked many tutorial and videos and I did not seen any further work. They just simple declare input field for ForeignKey attribute and its work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP.Net Core API bind model int Ids to custom Id objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58624805/asp-net-core-api-bind-model-int-ids-to-custom-id-objects)

Comment: No, he is dealing with HTTP get method. I have controller for post

Comment: And what is the difference?

Comment: Because you just pass `CustomerId`  from frontend, So `Customer = null`, `Customer` will not link to Customer model automatically, you need to pass it from frontend, But in my opinion, you just need to add ? to this property to make it nullable, then in backend link to Customer  manually.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are just passing customer id to the action and expecting from ModelBinder to create a customer object and map that id to it.

ModelBinder cannot create the customer object and pass the id to it , and because of that ModelState thinks that you have null entry that should not be null and raises that error for you.

By the way it's a bad practice to use your model directly in your action input and you should use **View Models(VMs)** or **Data Transfer Objects(DTOs)** for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Though this post is few month old, I'm just posting my solution here in case if it is helpful to anyone. I had a similar problem. So I checked the `Values` property in `ModelState` and the error was caused by the parameter passed to the post action. It is something like this:

```
 [HttpPost]
 [AllowAnonymous]
 public async Task<IActionResult> SampleAction(Sample model, string returnUrl = null)
 {
     ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
        ...
     }
}
```

The error indicated that returnUrl cannot be null. And there was a warning for the same parameter after compiling the code saying that non-nullable parameter has a null assigned. This is a common warning that you see with .NET Core 6 and higher versions. You have to create either a nullable variable or required variable. Since this action has the parameter set to default value null, I changed its datatype to a nullable string (`string? returnUrl`). That was the solution and `ModelState` error was gone.

I guess setting Customer property with nullable type could be a solution for this issue as it seems to allow null values.

```
public Customer? Customer { get; set; }
```

But it really depends on you system architecture to make nullable or required.

Answer (score -1):

Your model in this case includes a nested 'Customer' object. It is possible that the error is due to validation requirements defined in that nested object. Check the validation (data annotations) on the Customer object and see if any of those apply. CustomerId in your request should be binding to the CustomerId field of your PriceOffer model being bound in your Action method signature. Customer.CustomerId would try to bind to the nested object. It may be helpful to post the Customer object definition as well as the full request Url and request body/post data to see where the disconnect is.